# Remove twig include on specific template

Tags: twig

I'm trying to work this out and failing.

Say i have a base.twig where i want to output a heading. I want this on every child template that extends base.twig but one. Is it possible to remove an include from a page after running an extend?

base.twig

```
{% include "partial/heading.twig" %}
```

template-without-the-damned-thing.tig

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% some form or magic to make that damned heading not come out %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't 'uninclude' a template.

But there is an alternative: put the title in a block and override it by the child template:

> partial/heading.twig

```
{%- block heading -%}
    <h1>Your title</h1>
    <div>..</div>
{%- endblock heading -%}
```

> template-without-the-damned-thing.twig

```
{% extend 'base.twig.html' %}
{%- block heading -%}
{%- endblock heading -%}
```

Comment: It's not just a title, it's a large block of content that I don't want to include in the base template for obvious reasons. Hell it would double the size of my base twig.

Comment: Please share some information about your templates, because I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: This is the way to go. If you don't want a big chunk in your `base`, you just create an extra file which you can include

Comment: @StephanVierkant I've given an example in my question, though i don't see how it makes the question any simpler.

Comment: @ChrisMorris I've updated my answer based on your edited question.

Comment: @StephanVierkant That doesn't solve the issue of having to output the html into the base twig template though

Comment: Can you share partial/heading.twig? I think I still don't understand your question.

Comment: @ChrisMorris [this](https://twigfiddle.com/mwupgq) is what Stephan is suggesting. There is no "large block of html" inside the base template..;